# How to resize all MUI components globaly?

Tags: material-ui

I am working on a project that is based on react/mui. Overall every component should be a little bit smaller.
Especially Form Elements are to large and should be resized. In my case I want them smaller.

Is there any solution to set sizes for components globaly through`createTheme(...)`?

I found out there are some settings but those don't affect my form components, so that they are small enought.

```
const theme = createTheme({
  spacing: 4, // reduces some spacing like padding & margin on components
  typography: {
    fontSize: 12, // reduces base fontSize (=> shrinks some components because mui uses rem internaly).
  }
});
```

I want to use components in my JSX whith a default reduced size. So that the variant "normal" is per default smaller and also the variant "small" is per default even smaller.

```
<TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Outlined" variant="outlined" />
<TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Outlined" variant="outlined" size="small" />
```

I'm also happy if I could add a "tiny" variant alongside "small" and "medium".

Is there a clean and reliable way to implement this?